# How to rename SQL Server 2016 database including the physical files i.e. .mdf and .log files

Tags: sql-server

I have a database with lot of data which is used for my web application. For some reason I want to change the database name (phycially, .mdf and .log files).

How to do that?

Comment: for physical files, `detached` - rename - `attach`. For DB name, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/rename-a-database?view=sql-server-2017 . Note your existing App, jobs may not work after that

Comment: this method only renames the file in ssms and not the actual file stored in the folder

Comment: As in my earlier comment, you have to `detached` the DB, rename the files and `attach` back the DB

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command Rename-DbaDatabase that's present in dbatools.

```
Rename-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance sqlserver2014a -Database HR -DatabaseName HR2
```

This is quoted from the command's help:

The process is as follows (it follows the hierarchy of the entities):

- database name is changed (optionally, forcing users out)
- filegroup name(s) are changed accordingly
- logical name(s) are changed accordingly
- physical file(s) are changed accordingly
- if Move is specified, the database will be taken offline and the move will initiate, then it will be taken online
- if Move is not specified, the database remains online (unless SetOffline), and you are in charge of moving files
- If any of the above fails, the process stops.

**Please take a backup of your databases BEFORE using this, and remember to backup AFTER (also a FULL backup of master)**

For more information about the command you can look it up [here](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Rename-DbaDatabase).

Comment: dear sander, thanks for your message. i used your command via power shell but its only changing database name in ssms and not in the actual file located somewhere in my drive ..

Comment: @ghaffar-hunzai If you execute the following command you'll get all sorts of examples how to use the command: 
 
    `Get-Help Rename-DbaDatabase -Examples`
 
You actually have to set some more options to rename the physical files and possibly file groups.

Look at examples 4 to 11 to see what tags you can use to rename your database files